# ADF v2 Monitor Tab Activity Log Data - Written to a table

Tags: logging, azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring

I have a several somewhat activity heavy and slow pipelines that I want to speed up.

So my question(s) is, are the activity logging that can be seen under the Monitor tab in ADFv2 written to a table or other location that be queried/scrutinised ?

If not be default, can this be set and if so where and how?

Comment: Have you checked out [Pipeline Runs - Get - REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get#pipelinerun)? You can call the API and get the pipeline runs info. Afterwards, use any programming language you want to store to your storage and do your analysis.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to store Activity log as follows –

1. **Create a Stored Procedure Activity** - Updating Pipeline Status and Datetime columns in a static pipeline parameter table using an ADF Stored Procedure activity
2. **Create a CSV Log file in Azure Data Lake Store2** - Generating a metadata CSV file for every parquet file that is created and storing the logs in hierarchical folders in ADLS2
3. **Create a log table in Azure SQL Database** - Creating a pipeline log table in Azure SQL Database and storing the pipeline activity as records in the table

To get code and step by step procedure follow this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6320/logging-azure-data-factory-pipeline-audit-data/) by Ron L'Esteve